# Is it possible to get raw values of audio data using MediaRecorder()

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediarecorder, web-mediarecorder

I'm using MediaRecorder() with getUserMedia() to record audio data from the browser. It works, but recorded data is recorded in the Blob format. I want to get raw audio data (amplitudes), not the Blobs. Is it possible to do it?

My code looks like this:

```js
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false}).then(stream => {
    const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    recorder.ondataavailable = e => {
      console.log(e.data); // output: Blob { size: 8452, type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus" }
    };
    recorder.start(1000); // send data every 1s
  }).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MediaRecorder is useful to create files; if you want to do audio processing, Web Audio would be a better approach. See [this HTML5Rocks tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/#toc-webaudio-api) which shows how to integrate getUserMedia with Web Audio using `createMediaStreamSource` from Web Audio.

Answer (score 3):

No need for MediaRecorder. Use web audio to gain access to raw data values, e.g. [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/0s769z0d/):

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
.then(spectrum).catch(console.log);

function spectrum(stream) {
  const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
  audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream).connect(analyser);

  const canvas = div.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 20;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const data = new Uint8Array(canvas.width);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0, 125, 0)';

  setInterval(() => {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#a0a0a0";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(data);
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    let x = 0;
    for (let d of data) {
      const y = canvas.height - (d / 128) * canvas.height / 4;
      const c = Math.floor((x*255)/canvas.width);
      ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${c},0,${255-x})`;
      ctx.fillRect(x++, y, 2, canvas.height - y)
    }

    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(data);
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.beginPath();
    x = 0;
    for (let d of data) {
      const y = canvas.height - (d / 128) * canvas.height / 2;
      x ? ctx.lineTo(x++, y) : ctx.moveTo(x++, y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  }, 1000 * canvas.width / audioCtx.sampleRate);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to achieve an array of integers into console. As to what they mean, I assume they are amplitudes.

```js
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = async (blob: BlobEvent) => console.log(await blob.data.arrayBuffer());
mediaRecorder.start(100);
```

If you were to want to draw them, then I found this example that I had forked on codepen: https://codepen.io/rhwilburn/pen/vYXggbN which pulses the circle once you click on it.

Comment: Nope not amplitude. They represent the bytes of a webm audio file encoded by an opus codec. This is binary data, not raw signal.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex subject because the MediaRecorder API is able to record audio using multiple different container formats, and even further to that, it also supports several audio codecs. However, let's say you tie down your audio recordings to be of a certain codec and container type, for example, if from the front end you force all recordings to use the WebM container format with Opus encoded audio:

```
new MediaRecorder(stream as MediaStream, {
    mimeType: "audio/webm;codecs=opus",
});
```

If the browser supports this type of recording (the latest Firefox / Edge / Chrome seem to do it for me, but may not work in all browsers and versions thereof, for example I can see that as of right now, Safari only provides partial support for this and therefore it may not work in that browser), then you can write some code to decode the WebM container's Opus encoded chunks, and then decode those chunks into raw PCM audio.

I see that these WebM/Opus containers produced by MediaRecorder in Firefox / Edge / Chrome typically have a SamplingFrequency block and a Channels block at the start, which indicate the sample rate in Hz and the number of channels.

Then, they typically start clustering audio using Cluster blocks, which have a Timestamp block immediately after the Cluster block (but not necessarily guaranteed to be after, as per the WebM specification), followed by Simple blocks which contain binary Opus audio data. Clusters of Simple blocks are ordered by the timestamp of the Cluster block, and the Simple blocks within those clusters are ordered by the timecode header within the Opus audio chunk contained within them, which is stored in a signed two's compliment format.

So, putting all of this together, this seems to work for me in Node.js using Typescript:

```
import opus = require('@discordjs/opus');
import ebml = require('ts-ebml');

class BlockCluster {
    timestamp: number;
    encodedChunks: Buffer[] = [];
}

async function webMOpusToPcm(buffer: Buffer): Promise<{ pcm: Buffer, duration: number }> {
    const decoder = new ebml.Decoder();
    let rate: number;
    let channels: number;
    let clusters: BlockCluster[] = [];
    for await (const element of decoder.decode(buffer)) {
        if (element.name === 'SamplingFrequency' && element.type === 'f')
            rate = (element as any).value;
        if (element.name === 'Channels' && element.type === 'u')
            channels = (element as any).value;
        if (element.name === 'Cluster' && element.type === 'm')
            clusters.push(new BlockCluster());
        if (element.name === 'Timestamp' && element.type === 'u')
            clusters[clusters.length - 1].timestamp = (element as any).value;
        if (element.name === 'SimpleBlock' && element.type === 'b') {
            const data: Uint8Array = (element as any).data;
            const dataBuffer: Buffer = Buffer.from(data);
            clusters[clusters.length - 1].encodedChunks.push(dataBuffer);
        }
    }
    clusters.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.timestamp - b.timestamp;
    });
    let chunks: Uint8Array[] = [];
    clusters.forEach(cluster => {
        cluster.encodedChunks.sort((a, b) => {
            const timecodeA = readTimecode(a);
            const timecodeB = readTimecode(b);
            return timecodeA - timecodeB;
        });
        cluster.encodedChunks.forEach(chunk => {
            const opusChunk = readOpusChunk(chunk);
            chunks.push(opusChunk);
        });
    });
    let pcm: Buffer = Buffer.alloc(0);
    const opusDecoder = new opus.OpusEncoder(rate, channels);
    chunks.forEach(chunk => {
        const opus = Buffer.from(chunk);
        const decoded: Buffer = opusDecoder.decode(opus);
        pcm = Buffer.concat([pcm, decoded]);
    });
    const totalSamples = (pcm.byteLength * 8) / (channels * 16);
    const duration = totalSamples / rate;
    return { pcm, duration };
}

function readOpusChunk(block: Buffer): Buffer {
    return block.slice(4);
}

function readTimecode(block: Buffer): number {
    const timecode = (block.readUInt8(0) << 16) | (block.readUInt8(1) << 8) | block.readUInt8(2);
    return (timecode & 0x800000) ? -(0x1000000 - timecode) : timecode;
}
```

Note that your input buffer needs to be the WebM/Opus container, and that when playing back the raw PCM audio, you must correctly set the sample rate in Hz and the number of channels must also be set correctly (to the number of channels you read from the WebM container), otherwise the audio will sound distorted. I think that the `@discordjs/opus` library currently uses a consistent bit depth of 16 to encode raw audio, so you may also have to set the bit depth of the playback to 16.

Furthermore, what works for me today, may not work tomorrow. Libraries may change how they work, browsers may change how they record and containerize, the codecs may change, some browsers may not even support recording using this format, and the format of the containers may change as well. There are a lot of variables, so please take caution.