# Read microphone input in WASM

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I'm trying to figure out how to read microphone input in WASM (Rust), but I can't figure it out. I found a bunch of examples of generating audio output, but reading input doesn't seem to be covered anywhere. I was trying to convert some JS examples into WASM, but I failed.

I'm going to process the microphone input in WASM, so I'd need a solution that doesn't need to communicate too much with JS.

Comment: Note that the only input and output in wasm is with arraybuffers to/from javascript. Anything from web-sys just calls javascript functions. [This question seems to solve it in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61089091/6274355), which makes an `AudioContext` and moves the data into `Uint8Array`. You can then send that array's buffer to wasm.